# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE failes in postmeta table

Tags: post-meta, query, import, bulk-import

INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Mysql query is not working with Postmeta table. It adds new/duplicate rows to the table. I couldn't find a way to solve this. I need to use this as part of a bulk import script.

My query is:

```
INSERT INTO \`wp_postmeta\` (\`post_id\`, \`meta_key\`, \`meta_value\` ) 
VALUES (21100,"bygg_address","BILGATAN1 9 222B")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `meta_value` = "BILGATAN1 92 B";
```

Even though I have a row with 21100, "bygg_address", "BILGATAN1 9 222B", it inserts a duplicate row instead of updating it.

SHOW CREATE TABLE OUTPUT:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191)),
  KEY `meta_key_post_id` (`meta_key`(191),`post_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=221761 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably you haven't got a row with that key then if it's INSERTing a new one. Please add the full SQL you're using to your question.

Comment: @mozboz Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on `wp_postmeta`, I got the structure of that table which included this:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
```

So the key that MySQL can do the 'insert or update' on is the meta_id, which you're not providing. Therefore in your query, it will always be added as a new row.

EDIT: The docs for `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` say that it looks at either the PRIMARY KEY or any UNIQUE index, so you could possibly get around this by creating a new UNIQUE index on the combination of `post_id` and `meta_key` which might solve your problem.

**WARNINGS**

- If this is a big table for you that could be a bad idea because it might slow down some read or write operations.
- Wordpress or some plugin might be relying on the ability to have duplicate rows wiht the same post_id and meta_key, and this would prevent those being inserted. It seems like it would be a bad idea for code to do this, but it's perfectly possible.

**Solution:**

Tested this and it works for me:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD UNIQUE `post_metakey_index` (post_id, meta_key(100));`
```

With this index, if I run the query from your question twice, it first inserts it, then updates it.

Comment: Can we do it with post_id, meta_key combination? I've created a unique key combining post_id and meta_key. But it works just the same.

Comment: heh yes I just updated the answer with that as a suggestion.

Comment: It works for me, but please note you need to specify a limited length for the UNIQUE index - I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks. I checked this again. I have an index meta_key_post_id in the table. But it inserts new rows again and again with the given SQL query.

Comment: Do you know any other ways to insert/update postmeta with SQL query other than this?

Comment: This definitely works in MySQL and should solve your problem easily, so possibly you created the UNIQUE index wrong. Maybe share the current SHOW CREATE TABLE in the question text.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: You need to create the key as per my answer. When it's correct it will look something like this in
    CREATE TABLE: `UNIQUE KEY \`post_metakey_index\` (\`post_id\`,\`meta_key\`(100)),`